# Propagating $forceUpdate to slot contents

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm implementing a simple localization logic in Vue3. When the current locale is changed, each component that supports dynamic locale change must update its state. I currently do this via subscription to an event that calls the `$forceUpdate` method on the component:

```
<script setup>
    import { getCurrentInstance, inject } from 'vue';
    const $locale = inject('$my-locale-service');
    const $t = inject('$my-translate-service');
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    $locale.onChanged(() => instance.proxy.$forceUpdate());
</script>

<template>
    <span>{{ $t('foo') }}</span>
    <router-link to="page1">{{ $t('bar') }}</router-link>
</template>
```

So the problem is, `$t('foo')` is updated when `$forceUpdate()` is called, but `$t('bar')` isn't! Apparently, the redraw stops at `<slot>` boundary of components like `router-link`.

Is there any way to force redraw of the entire app, including all nested components? I can modify the contents of `$t` if needed to achieve reactivity, but not its signature.

The approach with `v-if` or `:key` which is sometimes suggested in articles does not work for me, because it flushes all internal state of the component, and form fields become blank.

Comment: This is most likely XY problem. You don't need a thing like forceUpdate under normal circumstances, not to mention the rerendering of the whole app. Consider asking about your real problem instead of potentially wrong solution for it. If it's your own l10n service then it's safe to assume there's a problem with its reactivity that wouldn't exist in existing libs like vue-i18n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct and well-working way was to do the following:

1. Define a reactive variable in the `$locale` service called `currentLocale`
2. Update the contents of this value when the user changes their preferred locale
3. Reference this value in the `$t` function

And voila, Vue reactivity makes sure every call to `$t` is updated whenever `currentLocale` changes. No need for dirty hacks with `$forceUpdate`.